# Should python mix-in classes inherit only from object?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I have a mix-in class called `WithAutoNumbering` for classes that need a special numbering of a given attribute. Appart from that I have a nice class mix-in called `WithIndexing` for those classes that need indexing capabilities... which needs the capabilities of `WithAutoNumbering`.

Some classes need numbering but not indexing, so mixing them together is not a good idea.

The dilemma is, **should `WithIndexing` inherit from `WithAutoNumbering`?** or each class that needs `WithIndexing` should also inherit from `WithAutoNumbering` as well?

I.e. this, with `CoolClass` being the one that has to implement indexing:

```
class WithAutoNumbering(object):
    ...

class WithIndexing(WithAutoNumbering):
    ...

class CoolClass(WithIndexing):
    ...
```

or this

```
class WithAutoNumbering(object):
    ...

class WithIndexing(object):
    ...

class CoolClass(WithIndexing, WithAutoNumbering):
    ...
```

On the one hand, the first approach is more succint, and makes sure that you can't try to use `WithIndexing` withouth `WithAutoNumbering`. On the other hand, I have always read (and found it agreeable) that mix-ins should not have hierarchy, i.e. inherit only from `object`, in order to avoid spaghettization of the whole class hierarchy with ununderstandable `__mro__`s

Comment: This question may fit better at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Certainly not. This is a technical question.

Comment: @Marcin Really? It seems like the OP is asking "which is the better design choice?" Isn't that one of the main topics of programmers.se?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo No, they're asking how to design this *in python*. Applying the religious concepts of OO design will seriously mislead.

Comment: @Marcin Surely the question could apply to any other language with mixins? It doesn't seem python specific.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Do all programming languages have exactly the same way of performing multiple inheritance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58439/discussion-between-colonel-thirty-two-and-marcin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with making a choice about what your mixins inherit from is that your choice will affect the final MRO of classes which use those mixins.

> should `WithIndexing` inherit from WithAutoNumbering

As you say, `WithIndexing` uses `WithAutoNumbering`. It's a funny kind of class which cannot be used on its own at all; and by inheriting from `WithAutoNumbering`,  `WithIndexing` can override `WithAutoNumbering` members.

In general, it will be easier for each level to override methods found above, the more you set this up as single inheritance.

However, if you choose to design the other way (such that you need to inherit from both to make a class capable of using `WithIndexing`), you will likely be completely fine, until something overrides a method found in `WithAutoNumbering`. In that case, the order in which the classes appear in the base list *may* affect their order of the MRO, in which case you may have surprising results. If you need the power to affect the MRO in that way, you should have each of these mixins inherit from object. You probably don't need that, though.

Answer (score 0):

The [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) applies. Would a class designed to work with `WithAutoNumbering` work with `WithIndexing` instead (whether or not it actually uses or needs whatever `WithIndexing` adds)? If not, then `WithIndexing` should just extend `object`.